# How do i make a coordinate system for a text based adventure game in python 3

Tags: python, coordinates, adventure

Basically, what that means is that i would like be be able to backtrack and go to areas that i've been to before. the method i've thought of is that when the user inputs the direction they want to move in, the corresponding coordinate adds 1 or subtracts 1 to the base coords, which is 0. this is what i have tried so far, but to no avail: (btw the last two prints are to see if it works correctly)(also, when i run the code, whatever i input, it just adds 1 to coordy)
`

```
coordx = 100
coordy = 100
direction = str(input("what direction do you want to go in"))
if direction == ("n") or ("N") or ("north"):
    coordy = coordy+1
elif direction == ("s") or ("S") or ("south"):
    coordy = coordy-1
elif direction == ("e") or ("E") or ("east"):
    coordx = coordx+1
elif direction == ("w") or ("W") or ("West"):
    coordx = coordx-1
print (coordx)
print (coordy)
```

Comment: Replace `==` with `=`. `==` is an equality comparison

Comment: i have changes it but it still doesn't work

Comment: Your brackets are wrong, change to e.g. `if direction in ("n", "N", "north"):`. You would otherwise have to write `if direction == "n" or direction == "N" or direction == "north":` p.s. you don't need the `str` on the `input`. You could also just transform the `direction` to be uppercase using `.upper()` and then you don't need to compare upper and lower case e.g. what happens if someone writes "North"